# How can I transfer to the cgi-bin dir of a remote web server in Aptana Studio 3?

Tags: perl, apache, webserver, aptana, cgi-bin

I'm running an Ubuntu 11.10 64-bit server on virtual box and want to seamlessly develop in Aptana Studio 3, but am having an issue.

I am able to upload to /var/www/ without any problem, except for having to ssh in to chmod the file but that's acceptable. I can't, however, create a Perl file and upload it to the /usr/lib/cgi-bin the same way. Also, if I create a Perl file on the server through ssh and then edit it in Aptana, i have to chown root:root it to be able to synchronize it.

Any help with this issue would be much appreciated. There is nothing about the Perl upload attempt in the Apache log if that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps it's a problem that the cgi-bin dir is not inside the www dir? You can update your Apache configuration to move it there if you prefer.